# How indexes work in composite key and how changing the order affects the performance in Postgres 12?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-12

```
 CREATE TABLE public.ABC (
    it_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    item_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (it_id,item_id)
);
```

When I use above query then index scan is applied when i query only by it_id or by item_id or using both.

But when I use the below then index scan is applied when I query with item_id or (item_id & it_id) . but not when I query with it_id only.

```
 CREATE TABLE public.ABC (
    it_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    item_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id,it_id)
);
```

Comment: How many rows do you have? How many unique values of it_id and item_id?

Comment: none. I was just using EXPLAIN after creating the table.

Comment: Don't verbally describe the queries you're running, actually provide an example instead. Every specific column referenced in the query can affect if you'll get a scan or a seek operation, so without seeing a full example query, it's not possible to fully answer you.

Answer (score 0):

An index on `(a, b)` is very efficient for searches that look like either of the following:

- `... WHERE a = 1 AND b = 'x'`
- `... WHERE a = 1 AND b > 'x'`
- `... WHERE a < 1 AND b = 'x'`

  However, and index on `(b, a)` would be better in this case.
- `... WHERE a = 1`
- `... WHERE a < 1`
- `... WHERE a IN (1, 2, 3)`
- `SELECT min(a) FROM ...`
- `... ORDER BY a, b`
- `... ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC`
- `... WHERE a = 1 ORDER BY b [DESC]`
- `SELECT b FROM ... WHERE a >= 1` (with a particularly edfficient index-only scan)

There are some less efficient uses of such an index, like

- `SELECT count(*) FROM tab`
- `SELECT a FROM tab WHERE b = 'x'`

These queries have to scan the whole index, but can avoid scanning the table.

It is also possible that the index is used for a query like

- `SELECT c FROM tab WHERE b = 'x'`

but that is the least efficient way to use an index, because the whole index has to be read *and* rows have to fetched from the table.

It may be that PostgreSQL judges that this last option is more efficient than a sequential scan in one of your cases, but not so in the other case.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: Sure, read [this chapter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html).